# Serializing struct containing vector of pointers with each pointer containing other pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, serialization, boost, deserialization

I'm trying to serialize a `minHeap` object which contains a vector and an integer using Boost.

```
struct minHeap {
    std::vector<keyNode> heapStructure; // A vector of many keyNodes
    int size; // Current size of vector
    minHeap() {
        size = 0;
    }
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned version)
    {
        ar & heapStructure;
        ar & size;
    }
};
```

Now the `heapStructure` is a vector of `keyNode` and each `keyNode` contains a character, integer and two pointers of the object `keyNode` itself.

```
struct keyNode {
    char data; // The character itself
    int frequency; // Occurances of the character in the data stream.
    keyNode * leftNode, *rightNode;  // Left and right children of the root node (the keyNode itself)
    keyNode() {
        data = NULL;
        frequency = 0;
        leftNode = NULL;
        rightNode = NULL;
    }
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned version)
    {
        ar &data;
        ar &frequency;
        ar &leftNode;
        ar &rightNode;

    }
};
```

The below (sample) code shows how I'm serializing and deserializing the file.

```
// Write Encoded Stream to File
ofstream outFile;
string outPath = filePath + ".enc";
outFile.open(outPath, ios::out | ios::binary); // TODO: Fix the output path
bitsetR bitStorage(outputStream);
boost::archive::binary_oarchive output(outFile);
output << bitStorage;
output << hTree;
outFile.close();
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("demo.txt.enc"); // TODO: Fix the output path
bitsetR bitStr("");
boost::archive::binary_iarchive input(inFile);
minHeap temp;
input >> bitStr;
input >> temp;
```

I don't get any errors while serializing but deserializing fails with the following error (VS 2017):

```
Exception Thrown: Input Stream Error (boost::archive::archive_exception)
```

I should note here that the `bitsetR` object deserializes successfully. The exception is thrown when deserializing the `minHeap` object.

Comment: What is the bitsetR? What is outputStream?

Comment: @sehe bitsetR is a boost::dynamic_bitset (I used the code in one of your answer to serialize dynamic bitsets). outputStream is just a string which I use to initialize by bitsetR object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all that's needed is proper flush and close of the archive and stream in the correct order. This code works ok:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70dd7725ee9ba909)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

struct keyNode {
    char data          = 0;       // The character itself
    int frequency      = 0;       // Occurances of the character in the data stream.
    keyNode *leftNode  = nullptr;
    keyNode *rightNode = nullptr; // Left and right children of the root node (the keyNode itself)

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
        ar &data;
        ar &frequency;
        ar &leftNode;
        ar &rightNode;
    }
};

struct minHeap {
    std::vector<keyNode> heapStructure; // A vector of many keyNodes
    size_t size() const { return heapStructure.size(); }

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
        ar &heapStructure;
    }
};

#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    minHeap hTree;

    {
        std::ofstream outFile("demo.txt.enc", std::ios::binary);
        {
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive output(outFile);
            output << hTree;
        }
    }

    {
        std::ifstream inFile("demo.txt.enc");
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive input(inFile);
        minHeap temp;
        input >> temp;
    }
}
```

Note I can make it fail with a similar message by dropping the scopes:

```
int main() {
    minHeap hTree;

    std::ofstream outFile("demo.txt.enc", std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive output(outFile);
    output << hTree;

    std::ifstream inFile("demo.txt.enc");
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive input(inFile);
    minHeap temp;
    input >> temp;
}
```

Prints **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/510c1cbc2871d5da)</kbd>**

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  input stream error
bash: line 7: 16838 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

Comment: It's working for an empty minheap. When I insert data in it (to form a tree) it shows the same error.

Comment: Can you post a minimal, self-contained example. If you need, you can start from [mine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70dd7725ee9ba909).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have fixed much of the code. Serializing and Deserializing works fine for small data. However with large data (for example 500 K) it fails.

Comment: And oh, the large object which isn't deserializing is boost::dynamic_bitset

Comment: All fixed. I have learned one thing. Never ever use mvcc (and Visual Studio). I'm going to trust GCC from now on.

Comment: Well. I'm going to venture that if your code doesn't work on one of those compilers, 99% says there is a problem with your code. Then again, if any compiler has a problem, MSVC is the most likely culprit, statistically

Comment: You're right about that. But I just couldn't figure why my code works fine for small files but throws the same input stream error for large files. It works when compiled with GCC and so I'll go with it. I'll upload my code on Github and will drop a link here for anyone interested.

Comment: Cheers. I'll have a look at it